# Pyorient SQL batch execution while ignoring errors

Tags: python, sql, orientdb, pyorient

I have done a lot of research but couldn't find a simple solution for the following problem.

I have an OrientDB database which has a "MaltegoLink" class. The MaltegoLink has an UNIQUE index to avoid duplicates.

The script itself follows the idea below:

```
self.client = pyorient.OrientDB(host, port)
self.client.db_open( database, username, password )

maltego_links = [{"source": "n1", target: "n2"}, {"source": "n2", target: "n1"}]
sql_batch = "begin;"

for link in maltego_links:
    sql_batch += "CREATE EDGE MaltegoLink FROM (SELECT FROM MaltegoEntity WHERE id='%s') TO (SELECT FROM MaltegoEntity WHERE id='%s');" % (link["source"], link["target"])

self.client.batch(self.sql_batch + "commit;")
```

The idea is to speed up inserts to the database by doing it as a batch.

**And the question itself:** 
How to make a batch query and skip errors provided by the database when there is a duplicate edge?

As far as I know there is no command in OrientDB SQL syntax that allows to continue if error occurs.

**EDITED:**

Ok, finally found some kind of workaround by myself. The method increases execution time but it is still beneficial:

```
LET t = SELECT FROM MaltegoLink WHERE in IN (SELECT FROM MaltegoEntity WHERE maltego_id="n1") AND out IN (SELECT FROM MaltegoEntity WHERE id="n2");

IF ( $t.size() == 0 ) {
    LET b = CREATE EDGE MaltegoLink FROM (SELECT FROM MaltegoEntity WHERE maltego_id="n2") TO (SELECT FROM MaltegoEntity WHERE maltego_id="n1");
}
```